# Code made elements don't show on onload?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been tasked with a demo for a query API our company has. For that, my boss wanted me to create a simple HTML site containing a search feature to use said API. So far, I've managed to create almost everything she wanted, but am now stuck on a rather... Peculiar problem.

I've managed to create a flexible filtering feature, allowing the user to add/remove filters as they see fit. I've done it like this:

```js
window.onload = function init()
{
 var filterSet = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[0];
 var filterSection = filterSet.getElementsByTagName("section");
 var set = filterSection[1];
 var elements = set.getElementsByTagName("*");
 set.getElementsByTagName("*")[5].addEventListener("click", cloneSection);

 if (filterSection.length > 2) 
 {
  elements[6].hidden = false;
  elements[6].addEventListener("click", deleteSection);
 }
 else
 {
  elements[6].hidden = true;
 }

}

function cloneSection(e)
{
 var filterSet = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[0];
 var filterSection = filterSet.getElementsByTagName("section");
 var newId = parseInt(filterSection[filterSection.length - 1].id) + 1;
 var set = filterSection[1];
 var newSet = set.cloneNode(true);
 var elements = newSet.getElementsByTagName("*");
 newSet.id = "" + newId;
 elements[5].addEventListener("click", cloneSection);
 elements[6].hidden = false;
 elements[6].addEventListener("click", deleteSection);
 filterSet.appendChild(newSet);
}

function deleteSection(e)
{
 var target = e.target;
 var filterSet = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[1];
 var filterSection = target.parentElement;
 filterSection.remove();
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
   <section>
   <input type="checkbox" id="filter_query" name="feature" value="search" />
   </section>
   <section id="0">
    <input type="text" name="filter_name">
    <select id="comperason_type">
       <option value="=">Equal to</option>
       <option value="!=">Different then</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="filter_value">
    <input type="submit" value="+" id="AddButton">
    <input type="submit" value="-" id="RemoveButton" hidden="true">
   </section>
  </fieldset>
```

It's rather basic (I'm kinda new to networking and Javascript as a whole, I'll admit), but for the most part it works just fine. Except for one single issue.

I want, when the user adds a new filter, to allow them to remove the default one created by the original markup. The button is there, I just need to set it to hidden = false and that's it. Except... When I try to do that, for some reason, the code doesn't recognize the extra section created into it. For example, if there are 3 sections in the fieldset, one created by my own code, the length count will only return *2.*

Does anyone know why? Or what can I do to get it to count properly? I'm sorry if this is a newb question, but like I said, I'm a bit out of my depth here.

EDIT: Made a snippet that works this time. Sorry for making it confusing, but it should be good now.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[1]` wil get the second fieldset in the document. In your snippet is only one so your code breaks. Use `document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[0]` to get the first one. And it's a good practise to check if the element is actually found.

Comment: But the code doesn't break. It works just fine (there are two fieldsets in there, I just showed the one that i need to work with.) Like I said, the only problem is that for some reason it still thinks that fieldset only has 2 children elements only it has more. The one children added by that script I made for it.

Comment: "In your snippet is only one so your code breaks." I'm talking about your snippet here. Please provide a snippet that reproduces your problem with minimal amount of code.

Comment: Okay... I rewrote it to work properly. Sorry again.

Comment: If you do it on the onload event it will only show the sections that are on the page when the page is loaded. So with 2 sections in your html it only show's these 2. If you check the `filterSection.length` in the clone function it shows the correct amount.

Comment: Yup... But I need to see it in the onload method too, so I can set the '-' button to appear properly. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The elements are not there when the onload event handler is executed. You can not count something that's not there. It's like: I want to count the trees in this park but I have to include all the trees that will be planted in the future too. To do that I need the data of the amount of trees to be planted from another source.